# php mail function sometimes send blank emails

Tags: php, email

I know how to use php mail() function. It works for me. But sometimes I am receiving blank emails with no message body, subject I mentioned in php mailer function with blank email id.
I did javascript validation for each and every form so that no field will be blank while submitting form.

After this validation also I am receiving blank email. Can any one please tell me why this is happening?

Note: I tried to submit form with blank spaces in text boxes but with blank spaces form is not submitting because of javascript validation.

**EDIT:**

code I used:

```
<?php
  $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
  $subject = 'the subject';
  $message = 'hello';
  $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
             'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
             'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

This is just an example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You have to handle special characters properly.

Comment: @Mani: Hello Mani it is simple code like `$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` this also sometime sends blank mail

Comment: @lqbal Malik: hey thnx for good reply. Can you show me some example. I am new in PHP. please

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (try 4th example)

Comment: @Ashish: hey thanks, that example I am using to send html page in email body.It also sends blank emails. Can you please tell me why this sends blank email?

Comment: @xyz : example which i send is working @ myside..check ur mail @ localhost by using: http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Comment: @Ashish: I am not saying its not working. It is working for me also. For my company website I am using same code. But sometimes it is sending blank email. This is what I want to ask here why **sometimes only** it is sending blank email.

Comment: @xyz You're better off validating at server-side level than client-side. That is the reason you're getting blank emails because someone disabled Javascript. You need to do this in your PHP handler `if(empty($_POST['email'])){ die("Enter your email"); }` and add the same for the other inputs in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it will be not possible to check what will be the issue. But below are some advice you can use :

1) Never use javascript validation, as it be bypassed, as it is client side not server side. Always use server side validation.

2) php mail function is good to use, but it is not feature rich. Try using [swift](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PhpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I just edited question with sample code.
I was using PhpMailer class to send email but sometimes mail sending fails and our customer response was bad about it. 

I will try to use swift. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Mandrill email sending is perfect. No blank mails sent using Mandrill...